# KDE Plasma - right-click Properties of Desktop icons drops to taskbar rather than opening in window

Tags: kde

Annoying problem.  If I want to view properties of any desktop icon, I right click properties THEN have to find in the panel / taskbar and click that to get the window to pop up that should have already popped up.

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS then added various desktops (XFCE4 & KDE Plasma).  The Ubuntu and XFCE4 desktops do not have this problem, only KDE Plasma.

Am I missing a simple setting or sumat?

Thanks,

Todd K.

Answer (score 0):

This is very surprising. I'm on 18.10, but I can't replicate it. I would suggest checking the "Window Management" section of the KDE System Settings to see if anything is amiss.